# create c# .dll compatible on both .net3.5 and .net4.0

Tags: c#, .net, dll, compatibility

I have to create a dll written on c#. The dll will have to be used on two different types on machines:
-MachineA that has got .net35 installed, but .net40 is not installed
-MachineB that has bot .net40 installed, but .net35 is not installed
Currently there is no option to install .net35 on MachineB, or to install .net40 on MachineA.

I would assume that creating a dll on .net35 would be able to be run on MachineB. But when I try to call any of the dll's functions, I get an error saying that the application needs .net35 to be installed

So the question is this: Is it possible to create the dll in a way that it will be compatible on both MachineA and MachineB?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your app to run on both versions of .NET (3.5 and 4.0) by adding multiple `supportedRuntime` values in `app.config` file

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

.NET Framework 4 and later uses `v4.0` runtime, .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 use `v2.0.50727` runtime. Also, since you are targeting old .NET 3.5, it'll make sense to enable [old runtime activation policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/startup-element), `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"`.

The configuration above runs your code on .NET 3.5, if only this version is installed. In case of both versions installed it'll will run on .NET 4.x

Yo can also have a look at this MSDN [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5#to-configure-your-app-to-run-on-the-net-framework-4-or-later-versions) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response! 
Further question: The C# dll will have to be used on a C++ code (I know it sounds a bit weird, but we have been given the dll's source code in C# and our main engine is on C++).
The above configuration will have to be done on the .dll project's properties? OR will it have to be done on the C++?

Comment: Well, it's complicated question, depends on which C++ are you using (managed or unmanaged) and how did you refer the C# dll. The `app.config` file is for .NET world only

Comment: But you have to compile it with a target framework of 3.5 I guess. Since you are not allowed to use new functions from 4.0

Comment: on C# I am using RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.dll to [DllExport("functionName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
Then on C++ I am using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to load the functions from the c# dll to out c++ engine. In this case, should I include the <supportedRuntime version= on the c# dll or is there no reason for it?

Comment: @StylianosPapadopoulos I think yes, you should add supported runtime to config and distribute together with dll. It'll be compiled into `your_dll_name.dll.config` Also you should add the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` to startup section, I'll update an answer above